# Matplotlib 3D scatterplot cmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

**edited to add example data

I have a dataframe which I am using to make a 3d scatter plot.

Two columns have information I want translated into the properties of the points.

Column Exp is which series the point belongs to - there are 7.  Each series has 9 points - this is the Day column which ranges from 0 to 8.

I would each series to be a different color - which the code below does well, but I would like each day to be an alpha so that they go from 0=light 8=dark.

Alternatively if each series had a unique sequential colormap with the gradient taken from the value in the day column that would also work.

Frustratingly simple but I can't quite get it!  Any help appricated.

```
anp = df.loc[:, 'Exp'].values
set_res = set(anp) 
list_res = (list(set_res))

d = df.loc[:, 'Day'].values
set_d = set(d) 
list_d = (list(set_d))

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') 
ax.set_xlabel('X', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Y', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_zlabel('Z', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('3D', fontsize = 20)
colors = ['r','g','y','b','m','k','c']
for target, color, day in zip(list_res,colors,list_d):
    indicesToKeep = df['Exp'] == target
    indicesToKeep = df['Day'] == day
    ax.scatter(data.loc[indicesToKeep, 'X']
               , data.loc[indicesToKeep, 'Y']
               , data.loc[indicesToKeep, 'Z']
               , c = color
               , alpha = day
               , s = 10)
ax.legend(list_res)

ax.grid()

plt.show()


    X               Y           Z               Day Exp
0   6.065799089     5.39606408  0.20680998      0   Exp1
1   -1.813171466    -0.14416587 1.152384796     1   Exp1
2   -3.676586344    1.358197191 0.882998403     2   Exp1
3   -5.074761537    2.214899107 -0.198255954    3   Exp1
4   -5.235090681    2.548416921 0.289574373     5   Exp1
5   -5.486962521    2.437908275 -0.496139886    4   Exp1
6   -5.939524094    2.939749551 -0.825422951    6   Exp1
7   -6.380253741    2.976652955 -1.3211511      7   Exp1
8   -5.952184603    2.80820602  -1.08558843     8   Exp1
9   6.501631702 6.755084113 0.056963689         0   Exp2
10  2.141323206 -2.942530182    0.276459756     1   Exp2
11  1.799786018 -2.761261089    -0.03426698     2   Exp2
12  1.58787416  -2.73071711 0.134785134         3   Exp2
13  1.731188598 -2.783161946    0.168444894     4   Exp2
14  1.959546043 -2.860391099    0.735327034     5   Exp2
15  1.763603911 -2.742837672    0.060296845     6   Exp2
16  1.84718194  -2.785950848    0.236620814     7   Exp2
17  1.986642504 -2.541517762    -0.773824298    8   Exp2
```

Comment: It would help to see your dataframe, preferable as a csv file. Consider posting it to an external link.

Comment: @pakpe I added some example data from the first 2 of 7 Exp series

Answer (score 0):

I was working on a graph similar to the case raised.
I think this can help:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,12))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') 

#colors = ['r', 'g', 'y', 'b','m','k','c']
colors_dict = {"Exp1":'r', "Exp2":'g', "Exp3":'y', "Exp4":'b', "Exp5":'m', "Exp6":'k', "Exp7":'c'}

ax.set_xlabel('X', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Y', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_zlabel('Z', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('3D', fontsize = 20)

for i in df.index:
    ax.scatter(df.X[i],
               df.Y[i],
               df.Z[i],
               color = colors_dict[df.Exp[i]],
               alpha = df.Day[i]/10,
               label = df.Exp[i],
               s=40)

# To avoid duplicated labels
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels()
by_label = dict(zip(labels, handles))
plt.legend(by_label.values(), by_label.keys(), loc = 6)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Another solution with good results is to use df.groupby(), and then iterate by name and group.

I hope it is useful to you.
Greetings